# No Sound card detected in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, 20.04

Using Ubuntu 20.04 and I am not able to increase or decrease volume in my laptop. Sound is coming but i can't change it. In setting/audio there is no output and input device detected.

[image: Settings image]

I tried these question already but none of them works for me.

> [no-sound-no-sound-card-detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413259/no-sound-no-sound-card-detected)

> [no-sound-card-detected-in-sound-settings-although-sound-work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155178/no-sound-card-detected-in-sound-settings-although-sound-works)

Ouput of `lspci | grep -i audio` command shows below result :

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```

**UPDATE:**

Output of `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` command

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 135
    Memory at b1328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: The question title is wrong. The device is detected as you can see. Also please don't post terminal output as a screenshot. You can copy text from a terminal.

Comment: Please post `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` so we can see if the kernel driver is being used.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I have updated the question. Please see